# How to get the same output using Excel-VBA code?

Tags: bash, excel, vba

I am working with an excel file, it only has one column as follows:

```
Type
A:\AAA\AD\RER\TES\11111\&DD&MM&AA.EXT
C:\AAA\CD\RES\TES\33333\&DD&MM&AA.EXT
C:\CCC\DF\WSD\&DD&MM&AA&SQ2.TXT
C:\DDDD\RT\FDG\334455&DD&MM&AA&SQ2.TXT
C:\DDD\YU\DFS\55555&DD&MM&AA&SQ2.TXT
C:\RRR\ER\SDF\55555&DD&MM&AA&SQ2.TXT
C:\TTT\CD\ERW\55555&DD&MM&AA&SQ2.TXT
C:\YYY\YU\WET\555555&DD&MM&AA.EXT
```

I would like to extract the following output:

```
&DD&MM&AA.EXT
&DD&MM&AA.EXT
&DD&MM&AA&.TXT
334455&DD&MM&AA&.TXT
55555&DD&MM&AA&.TXT
55555&DD&MM&AA&.TXT
55555&DD&MM&AA&.TXT
555555&DD&MM&AA.EXT
```

The approach that I followed to extract it was using bash since I am a beginner in the usage of excel, my command was the following:

```
rev colum.txt | tr -d " " | cut -d "\\" -f1 | rev | sed "s/SQ2//"
```

The problem with this is that I would like to achieve the same result using a macros of excel, I don't know how to program it, I would like to appreciate a suggestion of how to transform this bash code to Excel-VBA, supposing that the column that contains the data is the column A.

Comment: You don't need the bash tag, or the bash code-- just what you have, what you need, and how to do it in excel-vba

Comment: that was because, I wanted to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,9999)
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: this really helped me, I really appreciate the help, I just have a doubt, could you please tell me, what is the meaning of the last number I mean the 9999?

Comment: The **9999** is just a huge number to define the maximum number of characters to pickup after that last backslash